# Which is better optimized, to check if a list is empty or just iterate the empty list?

Tags: python

Is it necessary to check if a list is empty before using a loop?

```
import bpy

list = []

if len(list): # is it better to remove this line?
    for each in list:
        print(each)
```

Comment: if the list is empty, it simply wont execute the loop body,, TLDR no need to check if list is empty

Comment: Well that of course depends on what you want to do. Do you need to know whether it is empty or not for some other step, or `else` statement?

Comment: The preferred way to check if a list is non-empty is `if list:`. But as this is no cheaper than simply getting a list iterator, you needn't bother with the check.

Comment: Write code for readability and clarity. Don't worry about optimization until you have a reason to believe a piece of code is the bottleneck in your code. I assure you checking the length of your list is not a bottleneck in your code.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with @CoryKramer's statement.  It goes to something I was going to say.  Checking for an empty list adds some meaning to your code.  It says that you have consciously considered that the list might be empty.  Without it, those who follow, or even you yourself, can't be so sure you considered that possibility. - it's a subtle point, but then so is the whole issue.  In many cases, the answer will be "it doesn't matter".

Comment: I think checking for the length of the list could serve the opposite purpose for the reader - suggesting that the writer isn't confident in the workings of the `for` loop, and casting into doubt other basic things they may have misunderstood.

Comment: Its just for restoring something if its in the list so I never need to know if it is empty or not, just didnt know if an empty for loop is more expensive than checking if it was empty. Thank you all.

Comment: If code needs to convey the writer's confidence level, all bets are off in terms of understanding what the code should be doing.  My point was that which decision you make can convey meaning.  I didn't say that it's always right to check the size explicitly. - If the writer deems it to have the opposite effect in a particular case, then the answer is to not check the size in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write code for readability and clarity. Don't worry about optimization until you have a reason to believe a piece of code is the bottleneck in your code. I assure you checking the length of your list is not a bottleneck in your code.